# Customizing look of google map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I would change look and feel of Google map ,  is this possible .I would like to show only country co-ordinates.I want to show only countries with boundaries highlighted.If yes can you please let me know how this could be done.

Comment: Please do a little bit of basic research and attempt something on your own before coming here for a solution. Have you tried anything? Have you at least read anything? If so, include those details in your question.

Comment: I knew we could do the customizing but i dint knew to which extent

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, google maps has a full API that gives you loads of control over how your map looks.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

If you want to make life a little easier for yourself you can use this plugin.
http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/